# 2012 survey has some flaws

Tags: support, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I like filling out surveys, but this one looks a bit of a mess.

- "How would you best describe the industry you work in?"
- "What type of project are you developing?"

  - While it has an "other", I really don't feel like it's the best answer to the question if the answer is "I don't have a job".
- "What is your involvement in purchasing?"

  - <s>This sentence fragment is.</s> This is slightly confusing to those who don't have a job and so might not get that it means "What is your involvement in purchasing things for your company?" - especially since, again, there's no definite answer for the unemployed ("No Involvement", I guess).
- "Which languages are you proficient in?"

  - Minor niggle, there's no point in having a "none" checkbox.
- "Please rate the advertising you've seen on Stack Overflow"

  - Where do I put "No idea, I ignore the ads"? In the "ad blocker" section (that goes from 1-5 for some reason)?
- "Which languages are you proficient in?"

  - So HTML5 isn't the same language as the so-obsolete-it's-not-important HTML, eh?

Comment: For the proficient languages, why does it specifically say "HTML5"? Why not just "HTML" in general? The PHP option doesn't say "PHP5" and the CSS option doesn't say "CSS3".

Comment: @animuson: Oh my god you have no idea how annoyed I was when I saw that question.

Comment: I was a bit clueless because nowhere I could fill in I worked part-time, which of course has a big effect on income.

Comment: We need a survey on our satisfaction with the survey.

Comment: My favorite was "Have you visited / Are you aware of Careers Stack Overflow? () Yes () No". Um, well, "No, I haven't and yes, I am"?

Comment: @Problem: I figured `/` means `or`, but it is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: Ah, _logical_ OR, you mean? I suppose that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

"What is your involvement in purchasing?" isn't a sentence fragment.  "Purchasing" is a gerund (noun), and isn't being used as the present participle (verb).

Comment: I guess it's not technically a fragment, but the only thing I can answer it with is "Purchasing what?" The question is way too open-ended.

Comment: @Toomai I think it's intended to be open-ended, but I don't find it confusing. I don't purchase anything for my company, neither do most programmers. Anyone who is involved with purchasing -- something, anything -- for the company would describe what they do.

Comment: Well there's the problem, I couldn't make the connection to "purchasing something for the company you work for".